# Problems with NIntegrate, levmaxord error

Tags: numerical-integration

I am trying to integrate some spherical harmonics, for scattering over a sphere, using the `SphericalHarmonicY` and `NIntegrate` functions. When running `NIntegrate` I get this error:

> NIntegrate::levmaxord: 139.488 ((0.12318 +0.498137 I) E^(-3 I phi) Sin[the]^2-(1.58837 -0.0649687 I) E^(-3 I phi) Cos[the] Sin[the]^2) ((-0.201151+0.813455 I) E^(-2 I phi) Cos[the] Sin[the]-(1.269 +0.0519055 I) (1/2 E^(-2 I phi) Sqrt[105/(2 [Pi])] Cos[the]^2 Sin[the]-1/4 E^(-2 I phi) Sqrt[105/(2 [Pi])] Sin[the]^3)) is a Levin function of differential order 149 which exceeds value of option "MaxOrder" -> 50.
>       Treating 139.488 ((0.12318 +0.498137 I) E^(-3 I phi) Sin[the]^2-(1.58837 -0.0649687 I) E^(-3 I phi) Cos[the] Sin[the]^2) ((-0.201151+0.813455 I) E^(-2 I phi) Cos[the] Sin[the]-(1.269 +0.0519055 I) (1/2 E^(-2 I phi) Sqrt[105/(2 [Pi])] Cos[the]^2 Sin[the]-1/4 E^(-2 I phi) Sqrt[105/(2 [Pi])] Sin[the]^3)) as a non-Levin function. >>

It keeps running, but does not get anywhere. Any idea on how to fix this?

Here is a minimum working example:

`` (Clearing the memory of old calculations and constants)
ClearAll["Global`*"] ``

n12 = 1.33; n2 = 1.; [Epsilon]0 = 8.854187817*^-12;
c = 299792458; a = 2*^-6; [Lambda] = 1.064*^-6;

[Kappa] = N[2 Pi w0 n2/[Lambda]]; [Alpha] = N[2 Pi a n2/[Lambda]];
(*lots of calculations cut*)
faktorA[l_, m_] := 1. + 2.*I;

maxL = 4;

psi[l_, x_] := x*SphericalBesselJ[l, x];
psip[l_, x_] := (1 + l) SphericalBesselJ[l, x] - 
   x SphericalBesselJ[1 + l, x];
xi[l_, x_] := x*SphericalHankelH1[l, x];
xip[l_, x_] := (1 + l) SphericalHankelH1[l, x] - 
   x SphericalHankelH1[1 + l, x];

pn = Table[psi[k, n12 [Alpha]], {k, 1, maxL}];
ppn = Table[psip[k, n12 [Alpha]], {k, 1, maxL}];
x = Table[xi[k, [Alpha]], {k, 1, maxL}];
xp = Table[xip[k, [Alpha]], {k, 1, maxL}];
p = Table[psi[k, [Alpha]], {k, 1, maxL}];

(*Individuelle felt;*)
rField[c_, d_, l_, m_, the_, phi_] := 
  l*(l + 1)*c*pn[[l]]*SphericalHarmonicY[l, m, the, phi];
theField[c_, d_, l_, m_, the_, phi_] := [Alpha] (n12*c*ppn[[l]] *!(
*SubscriptBox[([PartialD]), (the)](SphericalHarmonicY[l, m, 
       the, phi])) - 
    d*m*pn[[l]]*SphericalHarmonicY[l, m, the, phi]/(n2*Sin[the])); 
phiField[c_, d_, l_, m_, the_, 
  phi_] := [Alpha] (m*n12*c*ppn[[l]]*
     SphericalHarmonicY[l, m, the, phi]/Sin[the] - d*pn[[l]]*!(
*SubscriptBox[([PartialD]), (the)](SphericalHarmonicY[l, m, 
        the, phi]))/(n2))

rFieldC[c_, d_, l_, m_, the_, phi_] := ((-1)^m) l*(l + 1)*c*pn[[l]]*
   SphericalHarmonicY[l, -m, the, phi];
theFieldC[c_, d_, l_, m_, the_, 
  phi_] := ((-1)^m) [Alpha] (n12*c*ppn[[l]] *!(
*SubscriptBox[([PartialD]), (the)](SphericalHarmonicY[
       l, (-m), the, phi])) - 
    d*m*pn[[l]]*SphericalHarmonicY[l, -m, the, phi]/(n2*Sin[the])); 
phiFieldC[c_, d_, l_, m_, the_, 
  phi_] :=  ((-1)^
    m) [Alpha] (m*n12*c*ppn[[l]]*
     SphericalHarmonicY[l, -m, the, phi]/Sin[the] - d*pn[[l]]*!(
*SubscriptBox[([PartialD]), (the)](SphericalHarmonicY[
        l, (-m), the, phi]))/(n2))

core[l1_, m1_, l2_, m2_] := Module[{},

a1 = faktorA[l1, m1];
   b1 = -I*n2*a1;
   a2 = faktorA[l2, m2];
   b2 = -I*n2*a2;

(* c,d as per Barton*)
   c1 = I*a1/(n12*n12*pn[[l1]]*xp[[l1]] - n12*ppn[[l1]]*x[[l1]]);
   d1 = I* b1/(pn[[l1]]*xp[[l1]] - n12*ppn[[l1]]*x[[l1]]);
   c2 = I*a2/(n12*n12*pn[[l2]]*xp[[l2]] - n12*ppn[[l2]]*x[[l2]]);
   d2 = I* b2/(pn[[l2]]*xp[[l2]] - n12*ppn[[l2]]*x[[l2]]);

sigma[the_, 
     phi_] := ([Epsilon]0*n2*n2/4) (n12*n12 - 
       1) (n12*n12*rField[c1, d1, l1, m1, the, phi]*
        rFieldC[Conjugate[c2], Conjugate[d2], l2, m2, the, phi] + 
       theField[c1, d1, l1, m1, the, phi]*
        theFieldC[Conjugate[c2], Conjugate[d2], l2, m2, the, phi] + 
       phiField[c1, d1, l1, m1, the, phi]*
        phiFieldC[Conjugate[c2], Conjugate[d2], l2, m2, the, phi]);

integrandS[the_, phi_] := 
    sigma[the, phi]*SphericalHarmonicY[4, 4, the, phi]*Sin[the];
   sigmaLM = 
    NIntegrate[integrandS[the, phi], {the, 0 , Pi}, {phi, 0, 2 Pi}, 
     AccuracyGoal -> 5];
   ];

core[1, 0, 4, -4];

Sorry about the clutter, the main thing about the integrand is that it is three SphericalHarmonicY's. Normally this "core" is ran with a bunch of different l1,m1,l2,m2, with the same for the l,m in sigma. A screenshot from the output:

[image]
I have other errors as well (everything becomes 0!), but I'd like to try to understand why this one comes about. All it does is increase the computation time and uncertainty, right?

Comment: Hi ! Please, post the code that is causing this error.

Comment: Done. Sorry about not providing the working example, it just seemed to add so much clutter.